# SOQL in Apex trigger returns [Name Set by Trigger]

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

Have 2 managed packages.

1. One package contains **Recurring** object.
2. Another package contains **Receipt** object.
3. **Opportunity** has lookup fields to **Recurring** object and to **Receipt**.
4. Created text field 'Donations List' on **Recurring** to see list of all receipts for this recurring.
5. Created trigger on **Opportunity** *after update* trigger checks if Opportunity lookup to **Recurring** is not empty execute SOQL to get all receipt names from **receipts**.

   `SELECT Id, Name, Receipt__c, Receipt__r.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Recurring__c=:recurringID`

The problem is - when **Receipt** creates it populates receipt__c field on **opportunity** and saves the opportunity.
On Saving **Opportunity** trigger fires to get receipt number populate into **recurring** object, but SOQL does not return correct receipt number. 
SOQL returns Receipt ID for Receipt__c field and returns  [Name Set by Trigger] for Receipt__r.Name.

Is there a way to get correct receipt number in this situation?

It seems like when **receipt** creates it has a trigger on insert/update that updates **Opportunity** lookup field Receipt__c. At the same time on **Opportunity** (using another trigger) I'am getting Receipt number of **receipt** that invoked opportunity changing.

Thanks,

Comment: What's the difference between receipt number and Receipt__r.Name (if there is one)? Also, are you literally getting a value of "[Name Set by Trigger]", or is it returning a name value from the wrong field or wrong record?

Comment: What are the managed packages? You may need to reach out to the vendor of the Receipt package to get clarity on exactly when the Name field is populated with its ultimate value, since it sounds like they may have some complex and possibly asynchronous code working there.

Comment: @Mobot818 receipt number and receipt__r.Name are the same. Field Name contains a number of receipt something like 'RT000012'
Yes SOQL literally returns [Name Set by Trigger] instead of actual Name I am expecting.

Comment: Can you insert Receipt__c  and see if it fires any Future/Quueable calls in Apex Jobs section?

Comment: @Pranay Jaiswal It doesnt fire future calls. It is just invoking one trigger from another.

Answer (score 1):

From the detail provided, it looks like the Name field for Receipt__c when created has initial value as " [Name Set by Trigger]". I believe there is some queuable, Future call going in the background which updates the Name with the actual value you see. 'RT000012' in your case

Whatever may be the case, the Name field is updated. I believe you can write a Trigger on **Receipt__c** after update. It will have the name present. Once you get the name you can query the related opportunity. From related opportunity, you can get Recurring records and then update the Donation list on it.